# Symfony: Let a bundle configure it's router

Tags: php, routes, symfony

I'm trying to build a system that is highly modular and provides the possibility to add not only new backend functionality but also new frontend pages and therefor routes to a system. Since Symfony already provides a bundle system I decided to use this as bases.

The list of loaded bundles will be taken from the database and can differ from one installation to another. Thus I cannot just write a routing.yml which will be loaded through my Kernel for all bundles. I tried some ways now to let the bundle itself provide a rounting.yml defining it's own resources & types but either I overwrote all existing configurations or I got errors for unknown services.

I also couldn't find anything in documentation or cookbook regarding this so I'd be glad if someone could offer a solution or at least hint me into the right direction.

Comment: Might tale a look at how cmf does it: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/components/routing/index.html or even Drupal 8.  It's not clear, to me, exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  If a new bundle is added then your control panel should generate a new AppKernel and rebuild the cache.  If you are trying to do things on a route by route basis then you may have issues.

Comment: Yeah the cache is rebuild, but I don't know how to configure the router to have multiple resources defined. Each bundle should provide it's own router configuration.

Comment: The obvious answer is that you would update app/config/routing.yml to pull in the new routes from the bundle.  But it seems like you would already know that so it is clear that I don't understand the question.

Comment: Yes. Updating app/config/routing.yml would be a solution, but to do so I would need to know which bundles will be loaded. And this can differ from one installation to another. So I don't know which entries should be in app/config/routing.yml until all bundles are loaded.

Comment: Sorry but that makes no sense to me.  Your AppKernel needs to know the bundles so whatever process builds it can build your routing file as well.  Again, I would suggest looking as some of the other Symfony based cms systems.  After all, routing is not the only thing you will need to deal with.  Many bundles require additional configuration at the app level.

Comment: Ok I was rather stupid. focused too much on the bundle itself loading routing resources. Created an algorithm that grabs configs provided by bundles and merges them into a ingle routing resource file now. This is then loaded on application level and it works as expected. Thanks for the hint.